# How to start up Win 8 without login into Windows Live account?

Tags: windows, windows-8

Mainly it's me using my PC, but when my friend comes over, he wants to login to windows and be able to play all the games I installed. 
Right now every time I login to windows I have to enter my Windows Live account passwords. I would like to know how to ignore this step for other users to login?

Answer (score 1):

Activate the `Guest` account and allow your friend to login with that. See [here](http://forum.technical-assistance.co.uk/activating-the-guest-account-in-windows-8-vt1795.html) for a step-by-step guide (there are lots of other ones on the web as well).

If Guest is too limited you can create a separate account for him.

Comment: Great! This looks like the one I want. I'll try tonight when i get home! Thank you Brad!

Comment: A separate account looks like the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Guest account or create a dedicated user account for your friend.

Then he will have access to all *desktop* applications installed on your computer, including games of course. He won't be able to access *Windows Store Apps* installed under your account.

A user account in Windows 8 can be local account or be associated with a <del>Windows Live</del> Microsoft account. To install Windows Store Apps, you have to associate the account with Microsoft account.

If your friend has a Microsoft (Windows Live) account, you can associate his user account with his Microsoft account. Alternatively you can create a local user account and *temporary* associate it with your own Microsoft account to install Windows Store Apps, if needed.